# Applying a new default sans serif to a watermark

Tags: fonts, xwatermark

I wish to change the default sans serif to roboto and use it for a water mark.

[image: Roboto]

When I pass a value to the `fontfamily` keyword of the `\newwatermark` function, the entire document changes font to sans serif. To prevent this I added `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}`.

However, the code below does not assign `sfdefault` to `fontfamily`. According to the **xwatermark** manual, `fontfamily` expects one of the default fonts, such as `crm`. I could not find a corresponding abbreviation of roboto.

How can I change the default sans serif font and set the watermark only to that value?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{T}
\author{AU}
\date{July 2016}

\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}    
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newwatermark[allpages,fontfamily=sfdefault,color=gray!25!white!50,angle=45,scale=4,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Lorem Ipsum
\section{Background}
Lorem ipsum... and then some
\end{document}
```

Comment: It'd be nice to have a fully compilable code…

Comment: @Bernard Consider it done.

Comment: A (hypothetically) last question: do you want  roboto to be tthe default sans serif font only for the watermark, or for the whole document?

Comment: @Bernard For the entire document, but that is not my priority.

Comment: My code realises that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of (one of) the font family defined by the package is `Roboto-LF`. Note you misunderstood the meaning of the `sfdefault` option of `roboto.sty`:  it means the `\defaultfamily` will be Roboto. Loading `roboto.sty` makes `Roboto` the default sans font, but doesn't touch upon the default family.

Also, the `Roboto` family has a rather large `x-height` as compared to Computer Modern or Latin Modern, so it should be scaled in case you use it in the body of your document.

Thus your code should simply be:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} \title{T}
\author{AU}
\date{July 2016}

\usepackage[printwatermark, ]{xwatermark}
\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}
\usepackage[scale=0.82]{roboto}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newwatermark[allpages,fontfamily=Roboto-LF,color=gray!25!white!50,angle=45,scale=4,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
{\sffamily Lorem Ipsum}
\section{Background}
Lorem ipsum... \textsf{and then some}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should do `fontfamily=\sfdefault`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}    
\usepackage{roboto}    
\newwatermark[
  allpages,
  fontfamily=\sfdefault,
  color=gray!25!white!50,
  angle=45,
  scale=4,
  xpos=0,
  ypos=0
]{DRAFT}

\title{T}
\author{AU}
\date{July 2016}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries DRAFT} % just to check

\section{Introduction}
Lorem Ipsum
\section{Background}
Lorem ipsum... and then some
\end{document}
```

[image]